# Error while initializing a Map in contract deployment

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

I was trying to deploy a vote smart contract on Tezos using tezos-client but because of initilization issue nothing was happening the right way.

The smart contract code in liquidity ( you can see the Mickelson code by compiling it with https://www.liquidity-lang.org/edit/ ):

```
[%%version 0.9]

type storage = {
candidates: (string, int) map ;
voters: (address, bool) map }

[%%init
let init_candidates (candidate_names : string list) =
let candidates =
  List.fold (fun (elt,map)  -> Map.add elt 0 map) candidate_names
    (((Map ([]))[@explicit_arity ]) : (string, int) map)
in
{
  candidates = candidates;
  voters = (Map : (address, bool) map)
} ]

[%%entry
let main (parameter : string) (storage : storage) =

let stroage =
  storage.candidates <-
    (match Map.find parameter storage.candidates with
     | None  -> failwith ("Candidate is not valid", parameter)
     | ((Some (x))[@explicit_arity ]) ->
         Map.add parameter (x + 1) storage.candidates)
in

(([] : operation list), storage) ]
```

Command used to deploy:

```
./tezos-client originate contract vote transferring 0 from alice 
running ../vote.tz --init '["Alice" ; "Bob" ; "Jack"]' --burn-cap 
0.429
```

Error:

```
At line 1 character 0, unexpected character [
At line 1 character 27, unexpected character ]
At line 1 characters 9 to 10, unexpected semi colon
At line 1 characters 11 to 17, unexpected string constant
At line 1 characters 18 to 19, unexpected semi colon
At line 1 characters 20 to 27, unexpected string constant
```

I found an other way to initiate the storager using "Paie" and "Elt", so I tried to deploy:

```
./tezos-client originate contract votesec transferring 0 from Khalil 
running ../vote.tz --init '(Pair {Elt "Alice" 0 ; Elt "Bob" 0})'
```

And I got this error:

```
Ill typed data: 1: (Pair { Elt "Alice" 0 ; Elt "Daly" 0 })
is not an expression of type
pair :storage (map %candidates string int) (map %voters address bool)
At line 1 characters 0 to 38,
primitive Pair expects 2 arguments but is given 1.
```

Can anyone help me out and explain to me what's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fyi: Liquidity is no longer an officially supported high level language in tezos. You may want to migrate your development to better offers including smartpy, ligo and lorentz

Comment: Thank you, it's solved by initiating this way:
`--init '(Pair { Elt "Alice" 0 ; Elt "Daly" 0 } {})'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After compiling in the liquidity IDE, we see that the type of the storage is

```
storage (pair :storage (map %candidates string int) (map %voters address bool));
```

For the initialization, the annotations (`:storage`,`%candidates` and `%voters`) can be ignored. As you can see, the type of the storage is a pair of values: the map of candidates and the map of voters. Whereas in your command line, you use the `Pair` constructor, but you give only value. Try this instead, where an empty map (`{}`) as the second component of the pair:

```
--init '(Pair { Elt "Alice" 0 ; Elt "Daly" 0 } {})'
```

You can also use the [try-michelson](https://try-michelson.tzalpha.net/) editor to obtain valid initial values for  the storage:

Comment: Thnak you! That solved my problem! This is the right command to launch: 

`./tezos-client originate contract vote transferring 0 from Khalil running ../vote.tz --init '(Pair { Elt "Alice" 0 ; Elt "Daly" 0 } {})' --burn-cap 0.815`